# Cannot update Visual Studio 2019 on a machine without Internet?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I created a offline installation following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019.

I also installed the certificates under ".\certificates". Then I run the following command in the installation folder

```
.\vs_Professional.exe update --noWeb --layout .
```

It got the error in the popup window.

> Visual Studio Installer
>
> Setup can't continue. We need to download some files to complete this operation, but the --noweb parameter was specified. Please remove the --noweb parameter and try again.

Removing the parameter will fail too because the machine doesn't have internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to remove the `--layout .`. The following command works.

```
.\vs_Professional.exe update --noWeb
```